# Web form submission directing my browser to the wrong page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, sugarcrm

I have a web form that sends the input to a SugarCRM database.  In order to have the form work properly on DotNetNuke, I have had to remove  tags and use javascript for the submit button.

The submit button looks like this:

```
<input title="Send Form" onclick="this.form.method='POST'; this.form.action='http://mplexuscrm.com/sugarcrm/index.php?entryPoint=WebToLeadCapture';submit_form();" type="Submit" />
```

When clicking the submit button, the form input is correctly entered into the database; however, the browser is redirected towards the admin panel of SugarCRM rather than back to the page I defined like so:

```
<input id="redirect_url" type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="http://mplexus.com/DICOMExtender/FreeTrialDICOMeXtender.aspx">
```

Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Have the admin panel redirect you to the value you like using the value retrieved from the form.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I apologize if this is a dumb question.  Am I looking for some type of dialogue box within SugarCRM that will allow a redirect, or does this answer involve a change to the form's code so that it doesn't automatically take my browser to SugarCRM?